# Duplicate row inserted after user submits a form - MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

I am facing a weird situation. I am trouble shooting an issue where a User was facing an error due to more than one record found for the given criteria

> invalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Upon checking the database records, there are more than one row inserted when user clicks on "Save" action which submits the form. But I am not able to reproduce this issue from my end, I have tried submitting form multiple times by multiple clicks but still data insertion is working fine without creating any duplicates.

I was looking into IIS log files and I noticed that user opened the web page but he was inactive for more than a hour and then submits the form. I suspect, this form submission created duplicate records in DB because after this step, User was getting Invalid exception indicating duplicates.

I can see more than one post request was created within same span of time but I am not sure whether user has clicked the Save action multiple times. But when tried this steps from my end there are no duplicates created.

I would appreciate any leads to simulate the problem and appropriate solution for this issue.

Comment: Does the form do a full post back and round trip i.e. you're not sending the form data using a javascript event handler on the "Save" button?

Comment: form does a full post back, not via any java script.  I am using Html.BeginForm() for posting data to the server.

Comment: What does your form's controller method do after executing the database insert(s)? Posting a snippet of the code used (minus any sensitive details) would be useful.